# pf not stopping bruteforce attempts

Tags: ssh, security, openbsd, pf

I am setting up an SFTP server for me and my friends and I am trying to stop brute force attempts.

I have read many articles on how to get pf to stop brute force attacks and am not having any luck.

I am running OpenBSD 6.4
Here is  my current /etc/pf.conf

```
#       $OpenBSD: pf.conf,v 1.55 2017/12/03 20:40:04 s then Exp $
#
# See pf.conf(5) and /etc/examples/pf.conf
set skip on lo
block return    # block stateless traffic
pass            # establish keep-state
# By default, do not permit remote connections to X11
block return in on ! lo0 proto tcp to port 6000:6010
# Port build user does not need network
block return out log proto {tcp udp} user _pbuild
ext_if="em0"
antispoof quick for ($ext_if) #No IP or GPS SPOOFING allowed here :)
table <bruteforce> persist
block quick from <bruteforce>
pass inet proto tcp to any:network port 22 \
        keep state (max-src-conn 10, max-src-conn-rate 5/5, \
         overload <bruteforce> flush global)
table <ssh_block> persist
block quick from <ssh_block> to any
```

When I checked the tables brute-force and ssh_block they didn't exist. So on ssh_block 
I ran the command

```
pfctl -t ssh_block -T add 218.92.1.138
1 table created.
1/1 addresses added.
pfctl -t ssh_block -T show
218.92.1.138
```

However my /var/log/authlog is still filling up with attempts from that ip address.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you reboot or run `pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf` after modifying that file?

Comment: I had an error on the config 

     `no IP address found for any:network`
     `/etc/pf.conf:22: could not parse host specification`
     `pfctl: Syntax error in config file: pf rules not loaded`

I commented out my other block rule. No errors now. however after I rebooted the server my ssh_block table is empty

Comment: You can't use `:network` on `any`, I think.  I just use `pass in on egress proto tcp to any port ssh` (etc.)

Comment: @Kusalananda please make that  an answer and I will accept it. I haven't received any more attempts from that IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was an error in the `/etc/pf.conf` file that prevented the firewall from loading its configuration at all ([`:network`](https://man.openbsd.org/pf.conf#:network) applies to a specific interface).

An example of using `pf` for blocking brute-force connections is given in [the OpenBSD PF FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/filter.html#stateopts), and it boils down to the rules (modified from originally being a `www` example to something I am using for `ssh`):

```
table <bruteforce> persist
block in quick from <bruteforce>

pass in on egress proto tcp to any port ssh flags S/SA keep state \
        (max-src-conn 5, max-src-conn-rate 5/30, \
        overload <bruteforce> flush global)
```

This would put any host that connects more often than five times every 30 seconds into the `<bruteforce>` table, which would block it.  It also only allows five connections per source address.

Another option is to use [SSHGuard](https://www.sshguard.net/).  There is a port of SSHGuard for OpenBSD, but it's very old (release 1.5 from 2011).  I've just (a few minutes ago) submitted an update to it which will hopefully be committed within a few days.